# Sending email to a user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this code to send email

```
var message = new MailMessage("abc@somedomain.com", "administrator@anotherdomain.com");
message.Subject = "Testing";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "<html><body>IMAGINE A LOT OF HTML CODING HERE</body></html>";
```

The problem is I just copied the HTML that I want to send as email and now I have to make the whole HTML code in ONE single line! Otherwise it is saying ";" missing! I mean, now I can't keep on removing spaces and put it ALL in one line! It's too much HTML code that I need to send. What do I do ? :/

**[EDIT] 
Another question: Is there a limit to this `message.Body`? Like a limit to how much HTML can be inserted in this?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dan has given one option - verbatim string literals - but I'd like to suggest that you move the data into a separate HTML file. Embed it as a resource within your assembly, and then you can load it in at execution time.

That way you'll get HTML syntax highlighting, you won't clutter up your code with a lot of data, and you can edit it really easily at any time, without having to worry about things like double quotes (which would need to be doubled within a verbatim string literal, or escaped with a backslash in a regular string literal).

The downside is that it becomes harder to put user data within the HTML - for that, you might want to consider using a templating system; either simply handwritten (`html = html.Replace("$user", name)`) or one of the various templating libraries available. Be careful to use HTML escaping where appropriate, of course.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `@` character:

```
message.Body = @"
    <html>
        <body>
            IMAGINE A LOT OF HTML CODING HERE
        </body>
    </html>";
```

This works OK if you have a small HTML markup / want a quick-and-dirty solution. For production code, I recommend you use what Jon Skeet suggests, keeping a separate HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your second question :

"The Body property can contain any object whose size does not exceed 4 MB"

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.body.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Put the text onto multiple lines?

```
message.Body = "<html><body>IMAGINE A LOT OF "+
                " HTML CODING HERE</body></html>";
```